# How to share providers between app / child modules in Angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a module which provides a config file using an injection token. The config file can be passed from the parent module using `ModuleWithProviders`

```
export class ChildModule{
  static withConfig(config: SomeConfigStructure): ModuleWithProviders<ChildModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ChildModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CONFIG_INJECTION_TOKEN,
          useValue: config.subSectionInConfig,
          deps: [APP_INITIALIZER]
        }
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

The module is then added to the app module like:

```
  imports: [  
    ChildModule.withConfig(config),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AnotherConfig,
      useFactory: ConfigFactory,
      deps: [Injector],
    },
    ...
```

When injecting these configs, Services provided by the ChildModule cannot seem to find `AnotherConfig` from the app module while other services, ChildModule or not, can't find anything for `CONFIG_INJECTION_TOKEN`

In both cases the error thrown is `NullInjectorError`.
Am I missing a property on the provider or do my provided instances get messed up because they are only available in their respective module ?

I should probably pass AnotherConfig to the ChildModule `withConfig` method as well so everything is provided by one module but the problem still remains.